# Can I use symbols defined in a .c file in a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I prefer coding in C but I'm using DirectX which is a massive pain to use without C++ so all my files are .c except the ones that deal with DirectX. However whenever I try to link a C file with external symbols that are in a C++ file or vice versa I get unresolved external symbol linker error. Is it possible to link a project that uses .cpp and .c and have the symbols be recognized?

Comment: Yes. declare functions with `extern "C"` that you want to use from either language.

Comment: With extern "C" ... Some massaging of the C++ code is needed, you can't expose classes and internal headers so some adapter functions and files are necessary. Basically you have to  expose "C" functions that call into C++ code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer True. That'll become a hard error. For POD:s, it''ll work fine though.

Comment: A general purpose way to use the same `.h` file for both C and C++ code is to use include guards around your symbols in question: `#ifdef __cplusplus` `extern "C" {` `#endif` and then the complement closing brace after all symbols `#ifdef __cplusplus` `} // extern "C"` `#endif`

Comment: What about for variables? I get an unresolved external trying to use global variables from a C file in a C++ one.

Comment: Then you link it wrong.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I usually keep my technology boundaries seperated. Keep all the C++ stuff internal and make "sdk's" to other technolgies wether they be "C", python or C# for example.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I define [extern int g_variable] in .cpp and [int g_variable = 0] in .c file what I did wrong

Comment: You did not link with the object file defining the variable.

Comment: I am using default linker options what must I modify (VS compiler)

Comment: You need all implementation files added to the project (or library part of the project). This part is not a problem with mixing C and C++. It's a general building/linking problem. Search for "_unresolved external symbol_" here on SO and I think you'll find a few Q&A's about it.

Comment: i got it thx for the help

Comment: I suggest you change the .cpp suffix to .c in VS.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use symbols defined in a .c file in a .cpp file?

Yes, you can, with the requirement that the names mustn't be reserved in C++ (such as keywords that don't exist in C etc.).

In order to use the C names in C++, they must be declared with C language linkage using a `extern "C"` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a Microsoft environment like Visual Studio.  If you open up the project properties, under **Advanced**, one of the options is **Compile As**.  There are 3 options

1. Default - .c compiles as C, .cpp compiles as C++
2. /TC - both .c and .cpp compile as C
3. /TP - both .c and .cpp compile as C++

If you wish to use extern "C", which is the option that most people go for, just leave it as default.  If you do not wish to use **extern "C"**, then try option 3 - compile everything as C++.

<s>Option 3 assumes you are no using c99 specifics like dynamic array allocation on the stack.</s>

Comment: "_Option 3 assumes you are no using c99 specifics like dynamic array allocation on the stack_" - Does MSVC even support that? That sounds a lot like VLA:s and MSVC doesn't support that - at least not directly but it has `_alloca`.

Comment: My bad - I've been using gcc and forgot that VS doesn't do VLAs.